# Scan directory names in php

Tags: php

I have a form where user enters few details, and a page is created dynamically using the post data. This is one piece of code where folders are being created based  on the input from $_POST['property_builder'].

What I need is, PhP should scan the directory names that is under Builders folder which exists on parent directory.

It should scan all the folders under Builders folders. Take it in a array -> later compare it with $_POST['property_builder'] if match is found a new html page needs to be created under the matched path.. I have the contents that has to be placed in the newly created page.

However, data needs to appended into the newly created HTML file.

```
if (!file_exists('Builders/'.$_POST['property_builder'].'')) {
    mkdir('Builders/'.$_POST['property_builder'].'', 0777, true);

}
```

Comment: Terrible idea to allow users define filepath.

Comment: I agree, but its for local admin only... not for public

Comment: I think u need to change the owner of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

To list the files and the folder, your can use the function `glob('Builders')` that will return an object of files and folders contained in the `Builders` dir.

To know if a folder exists, use the function `is_dir('Builder/'.$_POST['property_builder'])`.

Comment: Then, How do i create a file inside the found path when the match if found in globe function?

Comment: I have to scan the folder names not the file names!